# Coproduct in the category of vector spaces with bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, bilinear-form

I'm trying to work out the coproduct in the category of (say real) vector spaces equipped with bilinear forms, where the morphisms $(V,b) \to (V',b')$ are the linear maps $T : V \to V'$ such that $T^* b' = b$, that is, $b'(Tv,Tw) = b(v,w)$. It seems like it should be $(V \oplus V', b \oplus b')$ where we define $(b \oplus b')((v,v'),(w,w')) = b(v,w)+b'(v',w')$. However, if we take $(V,b)$ and $(V',b')$ to both be $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual bilinear form $b(x,y) = xy$, and apply the universal property to the pair of morphisms $\text{id} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\text{id} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, then this should give rise to a unique morphism $h : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $(x+y)(x'+y') = xx' + yy'$. But this is not true since there are cross terms in $(x+y)(x'+y')$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do we even know that coproducts exist? The usual arguments don't apply, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I've seen various sources claim they do...

Comment: The usual arguments _do_ apply to the category whose objects are triples $(V, A, b)$ where $A$ is a commutative ring, $V$ is an $A$-module, and $b : V \times V \to A$ is bilinear; but your category is only a non-full subcategory of this one.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Can you explain this in more detail? What are the morphisms? What are the coproducts?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg The morphisms $(V, A, b) \to (V', A', b')$ are pairs $(\phi : V \to V', f : A \to A')$ where $f$ is a ring homomorphism and $\phi$ is $f$-linear and preserves the bilinear form. I don't know what the coproducts are; they exist because it is a category of models for a finitary algebraic theory and hence locally finitely presentable.

Comment: @ZhenLin is $A$ commutative?

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $V$ and $V'$ are orthogonal with respect to $b \oplus b'$, i.e. we have $(b \oplus b')(v \oplus v')=0$ and $(b \oplus b')(v' \oplus v)=0$ for all $v \in V$, $v' \in V'$. In fact, $(V \oplus V',b \oplus b')$ represents the subfunctor of $\hom((V,b),-) \times \hom((V',b'),-)$ which consists of those pairs of morphisms $f : (V,b) \to (W,c)$, $g : (V',b') \to (W,c)$ such that $c(f(v),g(w))=c(g(w),f(v))=0$ for all $v \in V$, $w \in W$. Accordingly, you may view $(V \oplus V',b \oplus b')$ as the *orthogonal direct sum* of $(V,b)$ of $(V',b')$. Some authors omit the word "orthogonal" here (which might be confusing). As you have observed, $(V \oplus V',b \oplus b')$ is not a coproduct.

Notice that in this category, let's call it $\mathsf{Bilin}$, the object $(0,0)$ is initial, but it is *not terminal*. In fact, there is a morphism $(V,b) \to (0,0)$, and then it is unique, if and only if $b=0$. It follows that $\mathsf{Bilin}$ (unlike $\mathsf{Vect}$) has no linear structure. In fact, it is more or less a "geometric category".

The category $\mathsf{Bilin}$ has no coproducts. Assume for example that $(\mathbb{R},0) \oplus (\mathbb{R},0)$ exists, say $(U,b)$. Then we have two elements $v,w \in U$ with $b(v,v)=0$, $b(w,w)=0$, such that for every other $(W,c)$ containing two such elements $\overline{v},\overline{w}$ there is a unique linear map $f : U \to W$ such that $b(x,y)=c(f(x),f(y))$ and $f(v)=\overline{v}$, $f(w)=\overline{w}$. In particular, $b(v,w)=c(\overline{v},\overline{w})$. But there is no reason why the right hand side should be constant. It could be zero or non-zero, depending on the choices of $(W,c)$ and $\overline{v},\overline{w}$. In fact, if we consider $(0,0)$ with $\overline{v}=\overline{w}=0$, it follows $b(v,w)=0$. But if we consider $(\mathbb{R}^2,b)$ determined by $b(e_1,e_1)=0$, $b(e_2,e_2)=0$, $b(e_1,e_2)=b(e_2,e_1)=1$, and $\overline{v}=e_1$, $\overline{w}=e_2$, then it follows $b(v,w)=1$. This is a contradiction.

More generally, if $(V,b) \oplus (V',b')$ exists, it is likely that $V=0$ or $V'=0$. I think that this can be proven with the same method as above. Conversely, if $V=0$, then $(V,b)$ is the initial object and the coproduct exists of course.

A better behaved category is suggested by Zhen Lin in the comments.